# Can't display SQL database table to PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, datatables

I am trying to display a certain row of one of the tables in my database.

```
Here is my code for it:
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else printf("Connection Successful");

mysql_select_db('magento');
$query = "SELECT * FROM poll_answer"; 
$result = mysqli_query($query);


while($poll=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>" .$poll['answer_title']. "</td>";
}
```

And here is my table:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| answer_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| poll_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| answer_title | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| votes_count  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| answer_order | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I cannot get to print anything but "Connection Successful"!

Can anyone tell me what is possibly wrong?

**EDITED SQL to SQLI, still same problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Change

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($poll=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

To

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);
while($poll=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

[Check Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Comment: Did that, still nothing being displayed but connection successful!

Comment: Change `$result = mysqli_query($query);` to `$result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to `$conn` that is connection class object to `mysqli_query.`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: Yes! it was conn first and then query, as Sadikhasan stated

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're using both mysql and mysqli functions. Also, mysql is being deprecated soon, you might want to switch to PDO statements, it's fairly easy to setup, here's a tutorial that you could apply fairly quickly [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)